# Reducing 120 VAC to 24 VAC with a 5.1 Ω, 6.5 W resistor

Tags: voltage, resistors, schematic

Can anyone provide a schematic drawing to show how to reduce 120 VAC source voltage down to 24 VAC to power a small LED indicator light with a rating of 24 VAC/VDC using a 5.1 Ω, 6.5 W resistor?

Comment: No, they can't. It's not possible, nor would it be safe. That resistor can drop less than 6 volts before it overheats.

Comment: There is not enough information to answer this question. Depending on the LED current, you would maybe need in the range of about 1500 to 15000 resistors of 5.1 ohms. Please consider another way.

Answer (score 6):

The power dissipated on such a resistor would be akin to a space heater, and the "24VAC" LED would also need a stout shunt voltage regulator to shunt most of the (huge) current around it:
$$P_{5.1\Omega} = \frac{(120{\rm\,V}-24{\rm\,V})^2}{5.1\,\Omega} = 1.8{\rm\,kW}.$$

If you meant 5.1**k**Ω:
$$P_{5.1{\rm k \Omega}} = \frac{(120{\rm\,V}-24{\rm\,V})^2}{5.1{\rm\,k\Omega}}=1.8{\rm\,W}.$$

Now, that's more manageable. What current would be flowing through the resistor (and thus the LED, since they are in series)?
$$I_{5.1{\rm\,k\Omega}} = \frac{120{\rm\,V}-24{\rm\,V}}{5.1{\rm\,k\Omega}} = 19{\rm\,mA}.$$

The LED indicator actually has *another* series dropper resistor inside, but that won't matter all that much here. As long as its operating current is 20mA or more, it'll be operated within spec.

The circuit is just the resistor R1 and the LED indicator in series:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fy3dBh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The AC LED indicator has a built-in rectifier bridge and a series dropper resistor whose value I've guesstimated (it's in the right ballpark).

R1 cannot be just "any old resistor". For safety, it *must* have all of the following ratings:

- resistance 5.1kΩ, ±5% (or ±2% or ±1%),
- working voltage 200VDC (or higher),
- power rating 5W (or higher) - ample derating from 2W,
- **fusible**, surge-resisting design.

All nodes in the circuit must be well insulated. The indicator will indeed run from "24VAC", but that's **not** a safe-to-touch voltage to ground in this case, since the circuit is connected directly to mains. So don't let the "24VAC" rating fool you: everything in this circuit must be properly insulated and touching any wiring/conductive surface will not end well at all.

Comment: I really don't see why the resistor needs to have 5% or better tolerance.

Comment: @Justme Because a 5.1kΩ±10% resistor at the minimum end of the allowed values could have more than 30mA of peak current, which obviously is not a good thing for a 20mA LED.

Comment: In addition, I'm not sure how many fusible surge-resisting 10% resistors are not fake :)

Comment: I am not a fan of this circuit because it lacks a capacitor which would make the pulsating DC to steady DC.

Comment: @appliedSciences That should be inside the AC led already, I'd hope.

Comment: Actual AC/DC LED indicators don't seem to have diode bridges. They only have a reverse shunt diode across the LED. Check datasheets...

Answer (score 5):

tl; dr: XY problem. Use a capacitor in series instead of a resistor. Power will be substantially reduced and safety will be improved.

**A word of caution: all components in the circuit should be considered ‘live’ and thus housed in a suitable enclosure.**

Now, could 5.1 Ω ‘work’? By itself, no: it would nearly instantly vaporize the LED, as the indicator would only have its internal dropping resistor intended for 24V, not for ~170V peak.

Now, 5.1**k** Ω (I assume you meant that) could kind of work, although it’s a bit on the low side. I estimated the value to be in the 7-8k ohm range.

In the meantime we still have a problem. Let’s pretend we’re fixed on the idea of a dropping resistor straight from the line. **Way too much power being shed in the resistor** - even a properly-sized one, **because of the IR drop it’s being asked to handle.**

It's just silly, not to mention dangerous, to design such an inefficient system that makes so much heat, just to light an LED.

Instead, typical ‘line dropper' LED circuits like this use **series capacitance**, and also include **reverse voltage protection for the LED.**

Below is a circuit that shows this, for a ‘24V’ AC/DC LED with an internal resistor and reverse diode ([simulate it here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgA3cMFcY31gJR4o4EISpgS0DJASFMNPDSxgaoqjARsA7tyEjBIYoSi79x02AymTZgE4gUNKndzq7VFZHNGw-CzQRHz0jIJBsBF5wnwBjcBtLJ2ckqhRof1Is7Oy8ZnJWGmgosHk8aww8bBIIGDh2KV46AQlabAEA3gATBgAzAEMAVwAbABcmYYYusU0oWHZpl0kApfBW7r6hsfN211NI3k9zZrWvdvAadRC2jqbzmJ20JPdU82c95I9TH0cTtXU-jxRKw4Dsok58DcIcEwYdTCcjnoEfDzkYfAAHWh2Iw0bEBWpmJHYoHIwlYqwre6QnwAc0CkLCKU0bAARhFlCA8F4MOoUNh6D4AB4RJ6EUyEMD0Ei0C5OGgANQAOgBnACCAGEAPQAEXVKoAMgBRbUqnQAS1GAAsVWaAHajBj2W39YYqrr2AD26PRdppKvsDGVZuVow99mOcFOUKkzKRqJWkf8vB8HpA5EIV1okDI4GgKCQdXzol45GwbCAA)):

[image]

Here, the series capacitor is taking the bulk of the voltage drop, by providing **AC impedance**. The cap thus reduces the IR drop seen by the rest of the circuit, while delivering plenty of current to light the LED.

Notice the smaller series resistor value (470 Ω). You could use a 1/4W part for it. In fact, **with the series cap in place the resistor is actually not even needed** since not only does your ‘24V’ LED have an internal dropping resistor, but the cap is actually doing the ‘dropping’.

Instead, you adjust the LED current by **adjusting the capacitor size**, as it provides the bulk of the impedance. Compute this impedance as \$Z = \frac {1} {2 \pi fC}\$.

The 0.22µF shown provides about 12k Ω impedance, yielding 14mA peak. That’s plenty for an indicator. If you want max brightness, upsize the cap to achieve up to 20mA RMS.

**Caution: choose a safety-rated cap capable of withstanding line voltage.** A safety ‘Y’ cap that is designed to fail open would be best.

More about safety capacitors here: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/safety-capacitor-class-x-and-class-y-capacitors/

Now back to how 5.1 Ω could ‘work’. With the series cap doing the work of providing the needed impedance, the resistor *could* be 5.1 Ω. It could even be *zero*. In fact **it’s no longer needed at all.**

---

Exercise for the student: in the simulations, add a scope trace on the AC power source, select ‘power consumed’, then add a ‘show average’. What do you see? [hint: a terrible power factor, but very low power actually being used, mostly in the resistors.]

Next, try deleting *all* the resistors, including the one inside the indicator. Observe that the average power consumed decreases to just the power dissipated in the diodes - a dozen milliwatts or so. That’s a *big* improvement over 6W.

Comment: A comment on capacitor voltage rating and acceptable type would be a good idea. || Comment on other components may also be helpful just in case the OP attempts to copy the circuit.

Comment: Using a series capacitor is usually a valid design, but beware if the voltage source is not a clean sine wave of the specified frequency. I experienced field failures of a device using this method, where it apparently drew a lot more current than expected. I think the AC voltage may have been a "modified sine wave", which is essentially a square wave with dead time, so there were high frequency harmonics.

Comment: The cap should be sized for the RMS current so that the LED (and dropping resistor, if present) power dissipation is within limits.  As it is, an inverter making a square wave should have only 120V peak, not 170V, to have the same RMS as a sine. So it shouldn’t matter, unless there were some peaky hash/harmonics on the line. In that case a Zener across the LED would protect it.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: XY problem.  Use a [**transformer**](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Triad-Magnetics/F24-100-C2?qs=b1anAsPanWwzLBILBzDBmw%3D%3D) instead of a resistor.

Much safer as it provides isolation from 120V mains power, without the heat of the resistor.

Remember that even if you try to have the LED near neutral, all someone has to do is insert the plug upside down or use a miswired outlet, and the LED area will be hot at 120V.

Comment: There are many applications where there is no room for a transformer, or it adds too much cost.

Comment: @PStechPaul if you don't have room for a 10mm cube where will you find the room for removing heat from a dropper?  As far as cost, cost of a power resistor vs $2 transformer only matters if you're manufacturing at scale, which means you have a market, which means UL/CSA standards to meet.

Comment: I doubt that you could find, or perhaps even make, a 120/240 VAC 50/60 Hz transformer in such a small form factor. Of course, it would probably be most reasonable to use a tiny 24V switching supply.

Comment: @PStechPaul precisely why I linked an example of such a transformer. Gah, I wasn't paying attention, that one is wound for 72V,  but 120V isn't a problem.  It doesn't need to be 6W like the resistor, because it isn't *dropping* 6W resistively.

Comment: Primary inductance is only 150 uH, and specs are 50 *kHz* to 200 kHz.

Comment: @PStechPaul I see what you mean. That was a bungle on my part.  This one is more appropriate but it's 3cm on a side. https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Triad-Magnetics/F24-100-C2?qs=b1anAsPanWwzLBILBzDBmw%3D%3D. Still, doesn't need cooling and is more likely to make UL happy. Also available at low voltage if you  just wanted to drive a raw LED more directly.